# Get value of an object from Response entity

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, http-post

Hello I want to get a value of **fileContent** from the response string

My controller

```
@RestController
@Component
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class SigningControllerREst {
 @PostMapping("/uploadFile50")
        public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile50(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) 
                throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException, RubricaException  {
           ...
        UploadFileResponse up=new UploadFileResponse(fileName, fileDownloadUri,
                    file.getContentType(), file.getSize(),result);
            return new ResponseEntity<UploadFileResponse>(up, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

The Client

```
File inFile = new File("C:\\Users\\admin-pc\\Desktop\\CV.pdf");
FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(inFile);
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());

    // server back-end URL
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8094/rubi/rest/uploadFile");
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

    // set the file input stream and file name as arguments
    entity.addPart("file", new InputStreamBody(fis, inFile.getName()));
    httppost.setEntity(entity);
    // execute the request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
    String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity, "UTF-8");

    System.out.println(responseString );

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    System.err.println("Unable to make connection");
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Unable to read file");
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (fis != null) fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

The output

```
{"fileName":"CV.pdf","fileDownloadUri":"http://localhost:8094/rubi/downloadFile/CV.pdf","fileType":"application/octet-stream","fileContent":"Content in bytes","size":363629}
```

What I want is the value of ***fileContent*** (which was too long) from the **responseString**, How can I get that value .

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

you can get it like this:

```
Map<String, Object> responseMap = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper().readValue(fileContent, Map.class);

String fileContent = responseMap.get("fileContent").toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by just changing the return object the returned object from `UploadFileResponse` to `byte[]` 
Changed this line from

```
return new ResponseEntity<UploadFileResponse>(up, HttpStatus.OK);
```

to

```
 return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
```